# Average of Days between ordered dates per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, average

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
| EmpID | PerID | VisitDate |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|     1 |    22 | 2/24/2017 |
|     1 |    22 | 3/25/2017 |
|     1 |    22 | 4/5/2017  |
|     2 |    33 | 5/6/2017  |
|     2 |    33 | 8/9/2017  |
|     2 |    33 | 6/7/2017  |
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

I am trying to find the latest visit date and average days between visits per EmpID. For Avg, I'll first have to *order* the days consecutively and then find the average.

Eg: Avg. days for EmpID=1 and PerID=22 would be [29(Days between 3/25 and 2/24) + 11 (Days between 3/25 and 4/5)/2] = 20 Days.

Desired Output:

```
+-------+-------+----------+----------+
| EmpID | PerID | MaxVDate | AvgVDays |
+-------+-------+----------+----------+
|     1 |    22 | 4/5/2017 |       20 |
|     2 |    33 | 8/9/2017 |     47.5 |
+-------+-------+----------+----------+
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT
    EmpID
    ,PerID
    ,MAX(VisitDate) AS MaxVDate
    ,--Dunno how to find average AS AvgVDays

FROM
T1
GROUP BY
     EmpID
    ,PerID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    EmpID INT NOT NULL,
    PerID INT NOT NULL,
    VisitDate DATE NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (EmpID, PerID, VisitDate) VALUES
    (1, 22, '2/24/2017'),
    (1, 22, '3/25/2017'),
    (1, 22, '4/5/2017'),
    (2, 33, '5/6/2017'),
    (2, 33, '8/9/2017'),
    (2, 33, '6/7/2017');

-- SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

SELECT 
    db.EmpID,
    db.PerID,
    AvgDays = AVG(db.DaysBetween * 1.0)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        DaysBetween = DATEDIFF(dd, LAG(td.VisitDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY td.EmpID, td.PerID ORDER BY td.VisitDate), td.VisitDate)
    FROM
        #TestData td
    ) db
GROUP BY
    db.EmpID,
    db.PerID;
```

Results...

```
EmpID       PerID       AvgDays
----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
1           22          20.000000
2           33          47.500000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lag` to get the previous date and compute the date difference. Then use `avg` window function to get the average days.

```
Select distinct empid,perid,maxVdate,avg(diff_with_prev) OVER(Partition by empid) as avgVDays
from (
SELECT EmpID,PerID
,MAX(VisitDate) OVER(Partition BY EmpID) AS MaxVDate
,DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(VisitDate) OVER(Partition BY EmpID order by VisitDate), VisitDate) as diff_with_prev
FROM T1
) t
```

Comment: This seems to give 13 and 31 as the Avg Days for EmpID 1 and 2 respectively. Not 20 and 47.5. Because the Avg function outside is including 0 in the calculation so it's effectively calculating over 3 and not 2 in the mean.

Comment: Removing the default VisitDate on LAG does the trick for your solution

Answer (score 1):

The task is much easier than you think. You get the average with `(last visit - first visit) / (count visits - 1)`.

```
select 
  empid, 
  perid, 
  max(VisitDate) as MaxVDate,
  datediff(day, min(VisitDate), max(VisitDate)) * 1.0 / (count(*) - 1) as avgvdays
from mytable
group by empid, perid
having count(*) > 1
order by empid, perid;
```

The multiplication with 1.0 is necessary in order to avoid integer division. (You could also cast to `decimal` instead.)

As the calcualtion only makes sense for empid/perid pairs with more than one entry (and in order to avoid division by zero), I have applied an according `HAVING` clause.

Here is a test: http://rextester.com/AIFPA62612